# Android Studio - Import Project Error

Tags: sync, android

I copied the downloaded project to the root folder and then imported it into android studio. Instead of syncing the project, it throws the following error -

> 06:41 Gradle sync started
>
> 06:41 Source generation ended in 50 yr 1 mo 17 d 1 h 11 m 41 s 484 ms
>
> 06:41 Project setup started
>
> 06:41 Gradle sync failed: Unsupported method:
>   GradleProject.getProjectDirectory().          The version of Gradle you
>   connect to does not support that method.          To resolve the problem you
>   can change/upgrade the target version of Gradle you connect to.
>             Alternatively, you can ignore this exception and read other
>   information from the model. (1 s 400 ms)
>
> 06:41 Syncing only active variant             You can disable this experimental
>   feature from          File → Settings → Experimental → Gradle → Only sync
>   the active variant

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

In your `build.gradle` change the *Android tools* build version to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3'
```

or to something more recent.